# RXJava Ignore Error and continue in chain

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java

I have a RXJava chain where an error can be thrown.
I would like the chain to continue and ignore the error and reach the subscribe, for only some specific errors.

For example in this code

```
authDataManager
                    .getUserAccessToken(username, password)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .doOnNext({
                        authDataManager.saveUserAccessToken(it)
                    })
                    .flatMap {
                        appDataManager.getStations()
                    }
                    .doOnNext({
                        appDataManager.persistStations(it)
                    })
                    .flatMap {
                        appDataManager.getDriverInformation()
                    }
                    .doOnNext({
                        appDataManager.persistDriverInformation(it)
                    })
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(
                            {
                                onLoginSuccess()
                            },
                            {
                                onLoginFailure(it)
                            }
                    )
```

if `appDataManager.getStations()` throws an error, I still want to continue and reach the `onLoginSuccess()` method.

However if `getUserAccessToken(username, password)` fails, `onLoginFailure` should be called.

I have tried to add onErrorResumeNext() and onExceptionResumeNext() after the flatmaps and inside them, but if I do that, the chain just exits and doesn't continue and reach the subscribe

Comment: Are you dealing with an Observable? If so, you could just put the onLoginSuccess() in an onComplete, this will always get called regardless of success or error.

Comment: Yes it is a Observable. The problem that I want the onLoginFailure to be called if the first call (`authDataManager.getUserAccessToken(username, password)`) fails

Answer (score 5):

I figured this out in Kotlin [here (stackoverflow link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48229474/rxjava-filter-on-error/48231604#48231604)

It can be done by using a combination of mapping, filtering, optionals, and `onErrorResumeNext`.  I think this is about as graceful as it gets with the current version of RxJava.

```
authDataManager
    .getUserAccessToken(username, password)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .doOnNext({
        authDataManager.saveUserAccessToken(it)
    })
    .flatMap {
        appDataManager.getStations()
            .map(stations -> Single.just(Optional.of(stations))
            .onErrorResumeNext(error -> Single.just(Optional.empty()))                    
     }
     .filter(optional -> optional.isPresent())
     .map(stations -> optional.get())
     .doOnNext({
         appDataManager.persistStations(it)
     })
     .flatMap {
         appDataManager.getDriverInformation()
     }
     .doOnNext({
         appDataManager.persistDriverInformation(it)
     })
     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
     .subscribe(
         {
             onLoginSuccess()
         },
         {
             onLoginFailure(it)
         }
     )
```

Comment: This will handle the errors on `appDataManager.getStations()` stream, however, imagine if your `appDataManager.getDriverInformation` throws an exception - it will kill the whole stream and call `onLoginFailure(it)`. OP would like to skip the item if an exception occurs.

Comment: What you describe as a problem with my solution is exactly the behavior the OP requested.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `onErrorResumeNext` operator.

```
              authDataManager
                    .getUserAccessToken(username, password)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .doOnNext({
                        authDataManager.saveUserAccessToken(it)
                    })
                    .flatMap {
                        appDataManager.getStations()
                             .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
                    }
                    .doOnNext({
                        appDataManager.persistStations(it)
                    })
                    .flatMap {
                        appDataManager.getDriverInformation()
                    }
                    .doOnNext({
                        appDataManager.persistDriverInformation(it)
                    })
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(
                            {
                                onLoginSuccess()
                            },
                            {
                                onLoginFailure(it)
                            }
                    )
```

Comment: If I try that the chain never reaches the subscribe. I think the problem lies with `Observable.empty()`, because if I use `Observable.just(the return type)` it work.
However this is quite annoying because I have to create an instance of the return type of the flatMap

Comment: sure. it depends on your business logic.

Comment: The problem is that Observable.empty() does not call on `doOnNext` or `onNext`.. I wish I could do something like `Observable.just(null)`

Comment: why Observable.just not working for you? you can just return a new instance of your expected object.

Comment: well sure it works, but then my method `appDataManager.persistStations(it)` will be called and I have no way to avoid that.
If I could return a null value, I could check if it's null and not call it

Comment: You can try Observable.error(t) and check if it's an exception do not call persist stations?

Answer (score 0):

Standing on the shoulders of @savepopulation's answer, and using the observation that you have three distinct observer chains:

```
         authDataManager
                .getUserAccessToken(username, password)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .doOnNext({
                    authDataManager.saveUserAccessToken(it)
                })
                .doOnNext(
                    appDataManager.getStations()
                         .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
                         .subscribe( appDataManager.persistStations(it) )
                )
                .doOnNext( appDataManager.getDriverInformation()
                             .subscribe( appDataManager.persistDriverInformation(it)
                )
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        {
                            onLoginSuccess()
                        },
                        {
                            onLoginFailure(it)
                        }
                )
```

The main observer chain flows to completion, while the two subsidiary chains are not involved in the log at all; they are simply triggered by getting the user access token.

If you need those subsidiary branches to run asynchronously to the main chain, you will have to add `subscribeOn()`/`observeOn()` operators.